# Printing a string with start, stop, and step

Tags: python, list

```
hello = "Hello there"
print(hello[10:0:-1])
```

This outputs:

```
ereht olle
```

And I can't figure out how or why.

```
print(hello[10:0:-2])
```

And this one outputs:

```
eetol
```

Could someone please help me to understand what the [10:0:-1] is actually doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation is in order start, stop and step. So you start at index ten, go to index zero where the endpoint is exclusive with a step of negative two, meaning backwards two. Here is a diagram of indices:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# |  H  |  e  |  l  |  l  |  o  |     |  t  |  h  |  e  |  r  |  e  |
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#    X           5           4           3           2           1
```